# Faulty Ram? BSOD and Memtest errors

Tags: laptop, memory, bsod, memtest86+

Two days ago, my Laptop started to create masses of BSODs. First randomly while using, then after every reboot, when desktop was loaded. Finally it was so bad that i cannot start my laptop anymore. 
First i thought it's a software problem, so i tried to reinstall windows. But this also failed with BSOD while installing, Ubuntu Live freezes while copying files for backup.

Most of the BSODs were MEMORY_MANAGEMENT with address 0x00000000

So I tried to run memtest86 to check my RAM.

After 10 minutes i got over a million errors so i end the test and the result is:

- Lowest Error Address: 0x140229130 (5122MB)
- Highest Error Address:
  0x17D809140 (6104MB)
- Bits in Error Mask: 00000000FF000000
- Bits in
  Error - Total: 8 Min: 0 Max: 3 Avg: 1
- Max Contiguous Erros: 2

My Laptop is just 3 month old. It's a XMG P507 with 2x8 GB crucial ballistix Sport LT. The Ram timings are the default values in BIOS.

Question: What does that result mean. Is it a faulty ram? Is it just a problem with the timings? Voltage?
It seems it is a big range of damaged RAM, but only in one single block?

Comment: It means faulty ram.  Return it.

Comment: Instead of some odd memtest, you should use the standard Microsoft Memory Diagnostics. In many cases all internet tests would happily run, while the Microsoft test would show a problem. In your case the fault is so obvious, so you need to replace the memory. But try to re-seat it first, if it is in SODIMM formfactor.

Comment: I'm not able to get into window anymore, so windows tools are not an option. But thanks for your answers, i will check the ram blocks and slots now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One block was defect. The other ok. I removed and returned it. Everythings working fine now!